# Using disruptor in the Java Servlet and handling multiple events

Tags: java, disruptor-pattern, lmax

I am using the LMAX disruptor in my web application which takes the http request parameters and handle them to the ringbuffer. 3 event-handlers handle and process data, the final one, saves it to the database. 
Initialize the ringbuffer once, when the servlet is instantiated. is this right?

```
public void init() throws ServletException {

    Disruptor<CampaignCode> disruptor = new Disruptor<CampaignCode>(
            CampaignCode.FACTORY, 1024, Executors.newCachedThreadPool());

    EventHandler<CampaignCode> campaignDetailsLoader = new CampaignDetailsLoaderEvent();
    EventHandler<CampaignCode> templateEvent = new TemplateBuildEvent();
    EventHandler<CampaignCode> codeGenerator = new CodeGenerationEventHandler();
    EventHandler<CampaignCode> campaignSaveEventHandler= new CampaignSaveEventHandler();

    disruptor.handleEventsWith(templateEvent, campaignDetailsLoader).then(
            codeGenerator).then(campaignSaveEventHandler);
    this.ringBuffer = disruptor.start();
}
```

here I put the values straight into the ringbuffer

```
    @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException      {
    String campaignId = request.getParameter("campaignId");
    String campaignType = request.getParameter("campaignType");
    if (campaignId != null && !campaignId.isEmpty()) {
        long sequence = ringBuffer.next();
        CampaignCode campaign = ringBuffer.get(sequence);
        campaign.setCampaignId(Long.parseLong(campaignId));
        campaign.setCampaignType(campaignType);
        ringBuffer.publish(sequence);
    }
  }
```

event handlers

```
public class CampaignDetailsLoaderEvent implements EventHandler<CampaignCode> {
     @Override
public void onEvent(CampaignCode event, long sequence, boolean endOfBatch)
        throws Exception {
         //load details from db and process
         // udpate values to the event object
  }
 }

  public class TemplateBuildEvent implements EventHandler<CampaignCode> {
     @Override
public void onEvent(CampaignCode event, long sequence, boolean endOfBatch)
        throws Exception {
         // find the template of this type
         // set template to the event object
  }
 }

 public class CodeGenerationEventHandler implements EventHandler<CampaignCode> {
     @Override
public void onEvent(CampaignCode event, long sequence, boolean endOfBatch)
        throws Exception {
         // generate custom dsl code and execute it
         // update the output to the event object 
         //next handler will save it the db
  }
 }

  public class CampaignSaveEventHandler implements EventHandler<CampaignCode> {
     @Override
public void onEvent(CampaignCode event, long sequence, boolean endOfBatch)
        throws Exception {
         // save the details to db
         // done!
  }
 }
```

is this the right way to publish to the ringbuffer? do I need to synchronize the "ringBuffer" object? First 2 events run parallel, then the 3rd event. How should I handle this when I have fast publishers and slow consumers? I am using the disruptor 3.1.1, I could not find good usage example of disruptor in a web environment. A simple code implementation, if you have done one, would help me understand this a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This implementation is correct given the code requirements you've stated. Best practice is to wrap your publishing code in a try-finally block to ensure that a claimed sequence is always published:

```
long sequence = ringBuffer.next();
  try {
  Event e = ringBuffer.get(sequence);
  // Do some work with the event.
} finally {
  ringBuffer.publish(sequence);
}
```

It may also be a good idea to explicitly specify in the constructor that you need a multiple-producer Disruptor, but that is already done in the default constructor you've used. You should *not* synchronize writes to the `RingBuffer` as the process of claiming and publishing the sequence number is already thread-safe. Note however that there is no guarantee that the order in which events are published to the `RingBuffer` in concurrent invocations of `doPost()` will be the same as the order they're received by your web application.

The Disruptor is just a specialized queue and is therefore subject to all the usual problems they have with unbounded growth. If there are no available slots in the buffer, your call to `ringBuffer.next()` will block until one becomes available. You should both provide sufficient capacity to the `RingBuffer` to handle bursts of traffic, and consider ways to apply back pressure in the (hopefully rare) case that the buffer is filled.

In your particular use case, if the `CodeGeneration` or `CampaignSave` steps are taking a very long time compared to the first two, and can be deferred, it may make sense to use additional Disruptors/RingBuffers to queue up events for those executions.

Comment: That was really helpful, and one more question. Will this work as such with no code change when deployed as a clustered environment? How to cluster the Disruptor?